# How to easily convert fat32 local disk to ntfs?

Tags: ntfs, fat32

How to easily convert fat32 local disk to ntfs?
Can I do it without formatting the local disk?

Comment: you can, but you do have a backup, don't you? in case the poop is hitting the paddles. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a command prompt, enter **convert C: /fs:ntfs** .  You'll be asked to restart and the filesystem will be converted.  I've never had data loss doing this (a dozen or so times), but make sure to backup first.

Comment: restart is only necessary if the drive is locked by the OS.

Comment: You're right.  If it's the C: (or whatever drive windows is installed on) it'll be locked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the C drive by local disk, open up command prompt and run:

```
convert C: /FS:NTFS
```

answer yes to the prompts and then reboot.

Comment: FORMAT C:??? ah yes :)